# Using Settings Values in a code snippet for a Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently developing an extension for Visual Studio Code in which I provide some individual code snippets. I have also defined some settings for this extension. Now my question:
Is it possible to use values from my settings in a code snippet?
For example, I can also use the predefined variables ${CURRENT_YEAR}-${CURRENT_MONTH}-${CURRENT_DATE}

e.g..

```
`"myTicket": {
    "prefix": ["ticket"
    "body": ["My Ticket is ${TICKET}"]
  },`
```

TICKET is defined in package.json under configuration/properties ...

I also want to display the currently logged in user in a code snippet (environment variable %USERNAME%).

I hope I have expressed myself clearly. Unfortunately my English is not so good :-)

Many thanks for your help

I tried it with {TICKET}

Comment: Put the part about environment variable in a separate question post. You should generally only ask one question per question post. Even then, I don't think that question could be split into one question on how to get an env var and one on how to use any variable in a code snippet, and those two smaller question have probably been asked or may be simple enough for you to figure out on your own.

Comment: I doubt that you can do that directly.  You may have to make a CompletionProvider for that snippet and use a `SnippetString` as the inserted text.